# Docker install on Linux Mint 19 Tara

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, linux-mint, cinnamon

I tried to install docker on Linux 
Details as below -

```
    Mint version 19, 
    Code name : Tara,
    PackageBase : Ubuntu Bionic
    Cinnamon (64-bit)
```

Referenced link: https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/

Steps:

```
1. sudo apt-get remove docker docker-engine docker.io

2. sudo apt-get update

3. sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl software-properties-common

4. curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -

5. sudo apt-key fingerprint 0EBFCD88

6. sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
$(lsb_release -cs) \
stable"

7. sudo apt-get update

8. sudo apt-get install docker-ce
```

For step 6 I  checked lsb_release -cs

```
xxxxxxxxx:~$ lsb_release -cs
tara
```

I see issue at step 7.

```
xxxxxxxxxxx:~$ sudo apt-get update
Ign:1 http://packages.linuxmint.com tara InRelease
Hit:2 http://packages.linuxmint.com tara Release                                                                                                                        
Hit:3 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                                             
Hit:4 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                                                                                                     
Ign:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                            
Hit:7 http://la-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease                                                                                                   
Hit:8 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                                              
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [83.2 kB]                    
Hit:10 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                                                
Ign:11 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu tara InRelease                                             
Err:13 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu tara Release                         
  404  Not Found [IP: 2600:9000:2045:3c00:3:db06:4200:93a1 443]
Reading package lists... Done                      
E: The repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu tara Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

As an effect for step 8 I see below error.

```
xxxxxxxx:~$ sudo apt-get install docker-ce
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package docker-ce is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'docker-ce' has no installation candidate
```

Looks like there is some issue with linux mint Tara or Ubuntu Bionic with Docker.

Can someone tell me how to resolve the issue and install docker?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming, but about Linux usage. I suggest to re-ask this question on https://unix.stackexchange.com .

Comment: @peterh Not every question asked on stackoverflow is about programming. The topic raised in this question is genuine question as I didn't find any clear details in manuals on docker about installing on linux. Please see the answer for the topic to get more clarity.

Comment: @ShivrejJadhav Joining comment-chat [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52548029/virtualbox-install-on-linux-mint-19-tara#comment92102465_52548029).

Comment: FWIW i find la-mirrors.evowise to be very inconsistent. Try math.ucdavis.edu server instead

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The Docker repository at `https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu` doesn't know about Linux Mint's code name `tara`. Use Ubuntu's codename, `bionic`.

That is, your step 6 above should be this instead:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(. /etc/os-release; echo "$UBUNTU_CODENAME") stable"
```

This works because Linux Mint is built on top of Ubuntu. In this step, we are simply replacing the Linux Mint codename (returned by `lsb_release -cs`) with the Ubuntu base codename (returned by `. /etc/os-release; echo "$UBUNTU_CODENAME"`).

---

Because you already ran the incorrect command (with the Linux Mint codename), you might find that you continue to see warnings with `apt-get update`. To fix these, you can delete the corresponding file (the one that says `tara` from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`, or use another GUI or command line tool to do this for you.

Comment: Use "$(. /etc/os-release; echo "$UBUNTU_CODENAME")" instead of "$(lsb_release -cs)". It works I checked))

Comment: Great info! I'll add that to the answer above.

Comment: This doesn't work in linux mint 19.2. I've found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57402923/docker-installation-on-linux-mint-19-2-doesnt-work